# Ошибка при запуске Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

После установки андроид студио выбивает ошибку

> Error:CreateProcess error=216, Версия "%1" не совместима с версией Windows, работающей на этом компьютере. Проверьте сведения о системе, чтобы узнать, какая версия программы x86 (32-разрядная) или x64 (64-разрядная) вам нужна, и получите ее у поставщика программного обеспечения

Как это решить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Узнать версию вашей Windows (64-ех или 32-ух разрядная) и установить такую же версию Android Stidio и JDK (64-ех или 32-ух разрядную)

Comment: вполне логичный вопрос - и какая же версия у вас?)

Comment: У меня 32. Но на сайте нет выбора версии андроид студио

Comment: Может нужно другую версию Gradle?

Comment: Вы пробовали решение по ссылке, что я дал?

Comment: По какой ссылке?

Comment: в комментарии к удаленному ответу: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30045417/android-studio-gradle-could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-object-heap/31760855#31760855

Comment: Пробовал, не помогает

Comment: тяжко будет работать на x32, ресурсов не хватит для нормальной работы

Comment: пробовали и первый и второй вариант?

Comment: Да, и первый и второй

Answer (score 6):

1. Установите jdk1.8...
2. В AndroidStudio File->Project
   Structure->SDK Location, выберите местоположение директории JDK
3. Нажмите Ok.

По-умолчанию Android Studio использует встроенную (embeded) JDK, где может быть прописан путь к Java RE, а не к JDK. И по этим причинам она приводит к error=216.

Answer (score 0):

Да все так. Надо прописать путь к JavaSDK, указать папку,
например, "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0"

Answer (score 0):

У меня заработало так:

1. В AndroidStudio File->Project Structure->SDK Location.
2. Выберете Use embededded JDK. Нажмите ок. Запустите приложение кнопкой Run (снова появиться ошибка).
3. Опять зайдите в SDK Location. Снимите галочку с Use embededded JDK. пропишите путь C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121 <-ваша версия jdk.
4. Menu -> Build - Rebuild  project.